# Please provide the entire profile for moderator candidates

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, moderator-election, moderators

I'm reviewing candidates for moderator. I would like to see their comments and other actions like upvotes, downvotes and closures (in addition to questions and answers). The comments, upvotes, downvotes and closures are tucked away under *All Actions* tab of a profile. I can view mine, but I cannot view others.

Not being able to see full candidate profiles means we are getting a partial or incomplete picture of some of the candidate. I think getting the full or complete picture would help us make better selections. They indicate (to me) how the candidate will perform (assuming past performance is an indicator of future expectations).

I'd like to request the entire profile for moderator candidates be made available for inspection.

Comment: @animuson - What do you have to hide? Why is the site opposed to  transparency? More generally, what purpose does hiding information serve?

Comment: The reason why probably many will disagree with you is that many users probably will look if the candidates downvoted one of their own question/answer and maybe revenge downvote them.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I'm not really sure that's a compelling reason. There's always going to be some blowback. I get it multiple times I day for closing off-topic questions. Good with the bad I suppose.

Comment: [*"moderators have had disgruntled users repeatedly phone their place of work trying to get them fired"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283725) and such things happen just from sent moderator messages. Now imagine how many more times a moderator votes on stuff than they write moderator messages to users and if now every user can see what they voted on such things as quoted would probably happen way more than they already do.

Comment: @Rizier123 - That's interesting. I'm probably splitting hairs but... I see a sensational claim but no evidence to support it. Do you know where the first-hand account is for the story? Did one of the moderators blog about it? (I'd like to read about the details if the story is true).

Comment: @Rizier123 - I once had an Apple vice president named Price call my employer trying to run me off. My transgression was, I sent an email to an Apple security engineer I knew, and I asked him to enlist Apple to contribute to an OpenSSL FIPS validation for iOS. That really offended the VP for some reason. I think it was because Apple's security gear was stalled in the NIST process. For a time they could not get a validation. It took them 3 or 4 years to get one.

Comment: I don't know if any mod has blogged about this, but in this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous#comment919684_283725) there are some screenshots of stuff you probably get regularly as moderator.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to review *votes*. Votes are designed to be 100% anonymous, and the only reason you'd ever want to investigate those are if you suspected someone of vote fraud. Hopefully, you wouldn't even *consider* voting for someone that you suspected of engaging in vote fraud, so this should be a non-issue. I can understand wanting to audit closures, though, since these are actually review tasks and already publicly visible. At the same time, there are those users who go on *rampages* against people who've cast close votes, so this could have very undesirable consequences.

Comment: On a somewhat different note, I think you do have to be careful in assuming that past behavior is a perfect indicator of future behavior. I can only speak for myself, but there are certainly cases *now* where I cast close/delete votes on questions that are borderline. If elected moderator, I would not do that, because I would then have *binding* close votes and be acting as a representative of the entire community, rather than just on my own personal opinion. So while this is certainly a valid heuristic to understand someone's quality standards, it may not be exactly the data you want, either.

Comment: @jww - I've received multiple calls at my office by people very upset at moderation actions I've taken. One recent person who called was so insistent and hostile that we had to have the phone company block their number and my employees were pretty rattled by the incident. In just the last couple of months, another moderator did have someone make false allegations against them in an attempt to get them fired, so this has happened on multiple occasions. Few moderators write anything publicly about private moderation issues like this, and I don't know what positive would come out of doing so.

Comment: @CodyGray - *"So while this is certainly a valid heuristic to understand someone's quality standards, it may not be exactly the data you want, either."* - Right now, we have no data. I never thought I would encounter a process worse than the US election process. I think I found it here in cyberspace :) Even the US process allows us to know what a candidate has done in the past, and how he/she carries themselves. Here we vote mostly blind. We may as well throw darts at a board.

Comment: I don't see it that way at all, @jww, and I've voted in every moderator election that Stack Overflow has held. Only once did I vote for a candidate that I later regretted, and that was because I based my decision solely on what they wrote in the nomination and their answers to community questions instead of what I already knew about the person's moderation style from observing their previous activity on the site and on Meta. So, I mean, I guess it's true that it would be very hard for a casual SO user to vote in an informed way, but if you're a veteran who's been paying attention, it isn't.

Comment: @jww The *only* thing you don't know about a moderator candidate is their votes, which, as mentioned, has nothing at all to do with how they moderate.  You can *already* see their comments and close votes (at least on any post that has ended up being closed as a result) as both of those are all public.  You can also see all of their posts, all of their contributions to meta, aggregate data on all of the stats that *are* anonymous (votes and flags), etc.  You're not voting anywhere near blind.  The actual problem is that there's *so much* information that you don't have time to look at it all.

Answer (score 22):

You can already view summaries of their voting behavior, like any other user. Being a moderator, or, in this case, a candidate to be a moderator, does not mean that their anonymity in voting should cease to exist.

It's not about hiding information—it's about protecting them from abusive behavior. Moderators already experience enough abuse and harassment from users. So much so that [we recently had to anonymize moderator messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous) so users can't see which moderator sent them the message. Exposing their entire history of voting would only make it easier for users to target them with unsavory behavior of precisely the sort we're actively working to prevent.

If a candidate or moderator would *like* to make this information available, they have ways they can do so on their own. But we're not going to force the information to be public, nor are we going to spend resources making it easier to publicize.

Note that you can already see all of their comments by going to the "all actions" tab of their profile and then clicking on the "comments" sub-tab. If you'd like to view all the close votes they've ever cast, you can also access that information via the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: *"... you can also access that information via Data Explorer"* - You are assuming everyone can use the tool. I struggle with it for the simplest of tasks.

Comment: *"If a candidate or moderator would like to make this information available, they have ways they can do so on their own"* - As far as I know, there is no check box for "Share My Profile".

Comment: @jww And there never will be. I meant they have ways to access that information and they can share it any way they please on their own time.

Comment: @animuson I find this interesting *If you'd like to view all the close votes they've ever cast, you can also access that information via Data Explorer.* In which table would I find that? I can only imagine PostHistory and that holds at best successful closure. The Votes, ReviewTasks, and PendingFlags table are all anonymised. I'm pretty sure there are one or two open FR's on MSE that want this data added or for similar query support requests and I always had to give up on answering those. It would be great to learn what I have overlooked.

Comment: I hope you won't be ever convicted by an anonymous judge, for anything.

Comment: @jww All the really important infos are filtered out, and many trivial questions can be answered only by way too complex queries (which are hard to develop to not timeout). The few what remains, is far enough useful to worth to learn it. Asking your SEDE questions on the Meta SE is the only way to get there positively scored questions.